# Creating kinesis data stream with CDK (tries to create same stream again and again)

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis

In My CDK typescript stack, I crate a kinesis stream

```
import {Stream, StreamMode} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-kinesis";
...
export class KinesisDataStreamStack extends Stack {
...
   const stream = new Stream(this, "Stream", { streamName: props.streamName, streamMode: StreamMode.ON_DEMAND });
```

The problem is - for every deploy it tries to create new stream again and again. That is why deployment fails.

Question is:

- why it tries to create new stream, can not it be smart enough to figure out that it is already there? in the end of the day it is the configuration as code, not code as code.. if you know what I mean.
- even if I want to add that smart-ness manually with if (strem.exists):

---

```
let stream = Stream.fromStreamAttributes(this, "Stream", { streamArn });
if(!stream.streamArn) {
  const stream = new Stream(this, "Stream", { streamName: props.streamName, streamMode: StreamMode.ON_DEMAND });
 }
```

that still does not work: because [fromStreamAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_kinesis.Stream.html) - just creates the object that has nothing to do with reality (real one) - so if(!stream.streamArn) always true. (I tried [fromStreamArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesis.Stream.html#:%7E:text=of%20this%20construct.-,static%20fromStreamArn(scope%2C%20id%2C%20streamArn),-Import%20an%20existing)() too)

Question then, how to make it work?

Comment: Just check if `streamArn` was passed or not.

Comment: Does the stack deploy the first time then subsequently fail?  What is the deployment error message?  To answer your questions: Yes, CDK/CloudFormation is generally smart enough.  No, there is typically no need for a conditional resource check.